# Uploading direct CSV/XLS to tableau server using REST APIs

Tags: tableau-api

My objective is to create a datasource in tableau server and overwrite it each day with an a fresh csv/xls copy on my local system.

So far I have managed to connect to the tableau server using `tableau_api_lib` and its all good and working. However when I try to use `publish_data_source` function with my csv/xls it gives me below error, which is self explanatory

```
InvalidFileTypeException: 
        An error occurred while calling PublishDatasourceRequest
        The provided file extension 'csv' is not a valid Tableau datasource file extension.
        Tableau csv file extensions must be 'tds' or 'tdsx'.
```

my question is I don't have either of tds or tdsx file . what would be the best possible way to get out of this situationship?

Thanks

Comment: In your scenario, I would use the Hyper API to make an extract from your exce;/csv and publish that. There is not a way to programmatically make a tds/tdsx file.
https://tableau.github.io/hyper-db/docs/

Comment: Thank you. i think thats the right path to take